# A related rate question

Tags: calculus

**Question:** A tank for storing water is  conical in shape, with maximum radius 20 m and maxi­mum depth 15 m.  The large,  circular end of the tank points vertically upwards and 
is  open to the air.  It is  known that the volume of water in the tank will  decrease 
at a rate proportional to ***the area of the water's surface***,  due to evaporation.  Show 
that the water-level in the tank decreases at a constant rate.  If the tank originally 
stores  1000  $\mathrm{m}^3$ 
of water  and  the  water-level  drops  1cm/day,  how  long  will  it  be 
before  the  tank  is  empty?  [Hint:  A  cone  of  base  radius  R  and  height  h  has  a 
volume  $\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 h$].

**My Problem:** I have problem understanding what is meant by ***the area of the water's surface***? is it the area of circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is what is meant. In context, that's made (fairly) clear because they're talking about evaporation, which happens (almost) entirely at the air-water boundary.